# Custom BaseSpider Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to have some generic functionalities for spiders in a custom base spider class.

Usually scrapy spiders inherit from `scrapy.Spider` class.

I tried creating a BaseSpider class in the spiders folder of scrapy which didn't work

```
import scrapy


class BaseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def __init__(self):
        super(scrapy.Spider).__init__()

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

And here is my actual spider

```
import scrapy
import BaseSpider


class EbaySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "ebay"
    allowed_domains = ["ebay.com"]

    def __init__(self):
        self.redis = Redis(host='redis', port=6379)
    # rest of the spider code
```

Gives this error

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Then i tried to use multi inheritance and make my ebay spider looks like

```
class EbaySpider(scrapy.Spider, BaseSpider):

    name = "ebay"
    allowed_domains = ["ebay.com"]

    def __init__(self):
        self.redis = Redis(host='redis', port=6379)
    # rest of the spider code
```

which gives

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases

metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

I am new in python as well as scrapy and i am trying to implement my PHP style of coding in it which isn't working i guess.

I am looking for a proper approach.

Thanks

**Updated**

Changed the **init** signature as per scrapy.Spider

**BaseSpider**

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(scrapy.Spider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**EbaySpider**

```
class EbaySpider(BaseSpider):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseSpider,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.redis = Redis(host='redis', port=6379)
```

Still getting

```
File "/scrapper/scrapper/spiders/ebay.py", line 11, in <module>
    class EbaySpider(BaseSpider):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: Do you have the __init__()?

Comment: init in which class ?

Comment: Your first error with EbaySpider indicates that there is an issue with __init__. How did you define it?

Comment: @Torrinos I updated by code please check

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at `scrapy.Spider.__init__` [signature](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/5aebdac45d0563a17b7cd0d0da0078585d950605/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py#L26):

```
def __init__(self, name=None, **kwargs):
    # ...
```

Subclasses should define `__init__` methods with the same signature. If you don't care about name and kwargs, just pass them to the base class:

```
class BaseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

EbaySpider doesn't have to inherit from scrapy.Spider if it already inherits from BaseSpider. It should also have the same `__init__` signature, and it also needs to call `super()`:

```
class EbaySpider(BaseSpider):

    name = "ebay"
    allowed_domains = ["ebay.com"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.redis = Redis(host='redis', port=6379)
```

(I'm using Python 3 syntax for `super()`)

**EDIT**

There is one additional issue: you're importing BaseSpider like this:

```
import BaseSpider
```

Likely you have a module named BaseSpider (BaseSpider.py file), and a class named BaseSpider inside this module. `import BaseSpider` gives you *module* object, not the spider class. Try it with `from BaseSpider import BaseSpider`, and better rename the module to avoid confusion and to follow [pep-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: I tried implementing your suggesstion but still getting same error. Can you please check the updated part. I wonder how scrapy calls its scrapper because in their documentation they haven't mentioned anything related to custom parent spider classes at all

Comment: Even my Pycharm now behaving correctly :D Thanks alot bro ! Python is so different lol

Comment: Good luck in your Python adventures!

Comment: Bro, i can't access BaseSpider instance variables inside EbaySpider :(